# Is it possible to use regexp as variables to do find and replace in sublime text?

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I have a regexp search that looks like this:

```
'\d*.\d*, \d*.\d*'
```

I want to change the `'` and the `,`, but keep the d*. Is this possible in sublime text? If not, what's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This works the same way as most other places where regular expressions are available;

Group the parts of the pattern that you want to keep, and reference them in the replacement

Pattern: `'(\d*.\d*), (\d*.\d*)'`
Replacement: `$1 $2`

*This example will remove the `'` and the `,`*

Comment: just a tip, these replacements start with $0 ;)

Comment: @LuizRossi `$0` with regex replacements usually reference the entire match, while the groups start at `$1`. For the question asked here, the `$0` wouldn't help. However if you're looking to add something before/after every match, then `$0` would indeed be useful.

Comment: Just to add a bit of clarity: Let's say that you want to unquote all integer literals (`"123"` --> `123`), then you can simply use `"([0-9]*)"` as the pattern and `$1` as the replacement.

Comment: @303 you probably want to make that pattern `"([0-9]+)"` or `"(\d+)"`, because `*` means "zero or more" which means it would match `""` as well, and replace it with nothing, while `+` will ensure that there is at least one digit in there.